# Toggle row based on ID - Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a table, and when I click on some row, I want to display another row under it (with some info about that row). I dont know how to make it possible to toggle it, but also to be able to open multiple sub-rows. Somehow I need to enable toggle based on row ID, this is what I came up with but it doesn't really work like I need it.

```
<ng-container *ngFor=" let fields of mf.data; let i = index">
    <tr>
     <td (click)="expandCompareRow(i)">Something</td>
     <td>Something</td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngIf="compareRowExpanded == i && expandedRow">
     <td>Something</td>
     <td>Something</td>
    </tr>
    </ng-container>

    TS: 
    expandCompareRow(index) {
        this.compareRowExpanded = index;
        this.expandedRow = !this.expandedRow;
      }
```

This opens a row, but when I want to open another one, it first closes the row that is already opened, then I have to click again to open this row.

Comment: If you have a `compareRowExpanded`in your component, then obviously only one row can be expanded. You want each row to be expanded or not. So add an `expanded`flag to your Row object. And use `*ngIf="row.expanded"` and `(click)="row.expanded = !row.expanded"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `expanded` property with the object and toggle between it as below

```
<ng-container *ngFor=" let fields of mf.data; let i = index">
  <tr>
   <td (click)="expandCompareRow(fileds)">Something</td>
   <td>Something</td>
  </tr>

   <tr *ngIf="fields.expanded">
     <td>Something</td>
     <td>Something</td>
   </tr>
</ng-container>
```

typescript code

```
expandCompareRow(fields) {
    fields.expanded = ! fields.expanded;
  }
```

You can even do it without the method

```
 <td (click)="fields.expanded = ! fields.expanded">Something</td>
```